# Головомойка и выволочка

Tags: этимология, фразеология

"Головомойка" и "выволочка" означают разнос от начальства, наказание. А что плохого, собственно, в мытье головы и куда человека выволакивают? Просто, интересно было бы узнать происхождение данных выражений.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Головомойка - это строгий  выговор с нравоучениями, похоже на "промывание" мозгов от неправильных мыслей. Выволочка - грубый выговор,  нагоняй или побои, то есть  более грубое и серьезное наказание с возможным применением физической силы, дословно -  тасканье (волочение) за волосы.